# How to implement just in time access for a deployment server?

Tags: azure-devops

**BACKGROUND**

We are about to set up a deployment server that will be used to manage Azure resources. The deployment server will run pre-defined PowerShell scripts and deploy ARM-templates.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates) article describes how to use service principals and keys vaults so that the application that runs inside the deployment server securely can execute deployment scripts.

**PROBLEM**

Frequently, the deployment server will be updated with scripts, new pipelines, different types of configuration, code snippets, templates etc. When changes are made on the deployment server, we do not want the secrets to being exposed in any way.

**A JUST IN TIME APPROACH – CUSTOM ACCESS KEY API**

The functionality we are looking for can possibly be implemented with a custom access key API with the flowing workflow:

- In a service request portal, a deployment ticket is signed by an
  approver
- The deployment server receives the signed deployment ticket
- The deployment server sends the signed ticket to a custom access
  key API and receives a temporary service principal and access key
- The deployment server executes scripts (with the temporary service
  principal)
- The temporary service principal and access key is automatically
  removed

**WHY A CUSTOM ACCESS KEY API?**

The custom access key API adds the following capabilities:

- By comparison to a deployment server, the API has a smaller footprint and we believe that updates to the service will be rare and can be done in a very controlled manner.
- The API can give access to the deployment server based on the exact need (subscription, resource group, etc)
- The API can use digital signatures to verify the original approver of the ticket

**RECOMMENDED APPROACH?**

What is the recommended approach to implement just in time access for a deployment server?